# Edit a set of links in the Master page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have a set of links (not my navigation) in my bespoke master page which I would like to allow admin users to edit from the UI directly or even from a list. Is this possible via SharePoint desinger 2013?

Comment: You should place the links in a custom list and on page load read the list and populate the `a` tags

Comment: Can I do this via SPD 2013?

Comment: Yes. You need to edit master page and also should add JavaScript etc.

Comment: So I do this all client side, is this best practice for this type of thing? Thanks for the input

Comment: Yes.Client side scripting takes load off server, and hence it's best practice.